# Calculating the order of digital low pass butterworth filter

Tags: matlab, filtering, signal-processing

I am asked to design a digital low pass butterworth filter using MATLAB with the following specs :

1. cutoff frequency of 1.5 kHz
2. 10 dB stopband attenuation at 3 kHz
3. sampling frequency of 8 kHz

I have calculated the order of the filter to be 1.57. As we know we need to ceil this value to ensure that the filter satisfies the specs. However, in matlab I am using

```
buttord()
```

This function returns the lowest order which will be one in this case. So how do I return the highest order instead of returning the lowest order ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no highest order butterworth filter since any order greater than or equal to the result returned by `buttord` can satisfy the specs.

Since the sampling rate is 8kHz then the Nyquist frequency is 4kHz. If you assume 3dB passband ripple (which is standard), then calling `buttord` we get

```
Fn = 4000;
Wp = 1500/Fn;
Ws = 3000/Fn;
Rp = 3;
Rs = 10;
ord = buttord(Wp, Ws, Rp, Rs)
```

which gives `ord = 1`. Using the filter designer we can design such a filter and we see that indeed an order 1 butterworth filter exists which matches the specifications.

[image]

If you export the filter to your workspace (assuming you saved into `SOS` and `G` variables) then you can plot using `freqz` as follows

```
[b,a] = sos2tf(SOS,G);
freqz(b,a,[],8000);
```

---

If you want to design a filter using `butter` then you can use

```
[n,Wn] = buttord(Wp, Ws, Rp, Rs);
[b,a] = butter(n,Wn);
freqz(b,a,[],8000);
```

which results in exactly 10dB attenuation at the start of the stopband and less than 3dB attenuation in passband.

[image]

Comment: Thank you , put why i can't plot this filter response using butter() and  freqz() ? When i do so i get an empty plot for the mag. and phase responses . Please try it thank you

Comment: Edited. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thank you genius !

Comment: But how the empty  matrix [] have solved the problem instead of specifying the filter order n ?

Comment: The empty matrix is just a placeholder in the `freqz` parameter list. The 3rd parameter specifies the number of samples used to produce the plot. I leave it empty to let MATLAB decide how many samples to use. To reiterate the `n` argument in `freqz(b,a,n,fs)` is NOT the filter order and it needs to be any integer bigger than 1. Although bigger values produce more accurate plots.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification.